# Processos Ubuntu Server 12.04 rcuos

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Bom dia Pessoal, notei que após atualizar os pacotes do ubuntu server 12.04 o número de processos aumentaram drasticamente, rodando um ps ax encontrei essa lista de processos que nunca tinha visto antes...

```
    8 ?        S      0:38 [rcuos/0]
    9 ?        S      4:36 [rcuos/1]
   10 ?        R      0:07 [rcuos/2]
   11 ?        S      0:27 [rcuos/3]
   12 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/4]
   13 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/5]
   14 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/6]
   15 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/7]
   16 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/8]
   17 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/9]
   18 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/10]
   19 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/11]
   20 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/12]
   21 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/13]
   22 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/14]
   23 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/15]
   24 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/16]
   25 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/17]
   26 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/18]
   27 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/19]
   28 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/20]
   29 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/21]
   30 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/22]
   31 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/23]
   32 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/24]
   33 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/25]
   34 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/26]
   35 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/27]
   36 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/28]
   37 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/29]
   38 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/30]
   39 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/31]
   40 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/32]
   41 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/33]
   42 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/34]
   43 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/35]
   44 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/36]
   45 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/37]
   46 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/38]
   47 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/39]
   48 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/40]
   49 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/41]
   50 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/42]
   51 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/43]
   52 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/44]
   53 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/45]
   54 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/46]
   55 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/47]
   56 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/48]
   57 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/49]
   58 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/50]
   59 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/51]
   60 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/52]
   61 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/53]
   62 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/54]
   63 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/55]
   64 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/56]
   65 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/57]
   66 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/58]
   67 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/59]
   68 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/60]
   69 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/61]
   70 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/62]
```

Alguém faz idéia do que é esses processos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua atualização deve ter ligado alguma dessas flags:

```
CONFIG_RCU_NOCB_CPU
CONFIG_RCU_NOCB_CPU_ALL
CONFIG_RCU_STALL_COMMON
CONFIG_RCU_USER_QS
```

> O que é interessante é que aparentemente apenas no 13.10 elas vem ligadas como default:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Configs/RaringToSaucy

Leia mais sobre o funcionamento delas aqui:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.txt